# When we say a register has 32 bit, what does that really mean in assembly language?

Tags: assembly

According to wikipedia,

> 32-bit registers can store 2<sup>32</sup> different values different values. It
>   goes further into saying "  With the two most common representations,
>   the range is 0 through 4,294,967,295 (2<sup>32</sup> - 1) for representation as
>   an (unsigned) binary number, and -2,147,483,648 (-2<sup>31</sup>) through
>   2,147,483,647 (2<sup>31</sup> - 1) for  representation as Two's complement"

So how does that translate into a real example?

a. Does it mean I can store 0 and 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 .... 4,294,967,295 in a 32 bit register?

b. What if I wanted to store the same number, say for in the same register 4294967296 times. Can I do that?

c. Is there a way to appropriately calculate when it will start overflowing?  I don't know if each integer has  a specific number of bits (like a price tag) that we can add up to calculate when it will start overflowing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not (yet) a programming question.

Comment: @RaymondChen Despite the question does not contain any code, it surely touches basic topics about programming. Not sure if this is enough for Stack Overflow however...?

Comment: @coolparadox It's more conceptual than directly related to a specific programming problem, so it's not really on topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. It means you can store value 0 **or** 1 **or** 2 ... **or** 4,294,967,295 in the register.
2. Yes, although storing the same value just once would suffice as the register can be read an infinite number of times.
3. Virtually all microprocessors implement a *carry flag* that is set when the result of an arithmetic operation (such as adding two numbers) cannot be stored in the answer register due to insufficient bit depth. This can be used as a form of overflow detection in assembly language.